# Flexbox many nested children

Tags: html, css, flexbox, sticky-footer

I've read many posts on flexbox but still have an issue that bugs me.
I want to have a sticky footer using flexbox as per [this guide](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/).

But then, inside my page content I would like to have as many nested `div`s I like and have them taking the same height of the parent.

The problem is, setting `height: 100%` on each child (as I would do in a non-flexbox scenario) works differently when flexbox is enabled. This results in the children getting more height (overflow the parent).

To make this more clear here's a [codepen without flexbox](http://codepen.io/stilllife00/pen/xZOKLX)

and a [codepen with flexbox](http://codepen.io/stilllife00/pen/yeJBVY)

You can see in the flexbox scenario the footer gets the green bakground even if I don't want that.

HTML:

```
<div class="sticky-footer-container">
  <div class="sticky-footer-content">
    <div class="page-container">
      <div class="main-menu">
        <div class="main-menu-selection">
          <div class="main-menu-selection-text">
            <div class="some-other-class">
              Some text
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main-menu-selection">
          <div class="main-menu-selection-text">
            <div class="some-other-class">
              Some text
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sticky-footer">
    Some footer content
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: silver;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sticky-footer-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  .sticky-footer-content {
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    flex: 1;
    div {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .main-menu-selection {
      height: 50%;
    }
  }
}

.some-other-class {
  background: green;
}
```

In order to solve this, ANY nested div has to become a `flex-container` ?

In other words, is there any way to "stop the flex propagation" at some point of the tree, so all the divs gets the parent height without overflow?

Comment: The example which you provide doesn't seem to demonstrate the problem which you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

`display:`**`flexbox`** is not really a valid value :)

you need to set height as well and eventually inherit it from html :

```css
.sticky-footer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sticky-footer-content {
  flex: 1;
}
/* let's inherit some height to pull the footer down */
html,
body,
.sticky-footer-container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.sticky-footer {
  display: flex;/* flex item can be flexboxes as well */
  background: turquoise;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky-footer-container">
  <div class="sticky-footer-content">
    <div class="page-container">
      <div class="main-menu">
        <div class="main-menu-selection">
          <div class="main-menu-selection-text">
            <div class="some-other-class">
              Some text
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main-menu-selection">
          <div class="main-menu-selection-text">
            <div class="some-other-class">
              Some text
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sticky-footer">
    Here my footer
  </div>
</div>
```